# Java String-buffer - How to count occurrence of specific word in a string

Tags: java, stringbuffer

All,

I need to count the specific word from a string in stringbuffer. i have made a program (please see below) to count a specific char in a string but not sure how to do this for a word. for example... my string is "Cat can kill mouse but mouse can not kill cat". I need to count how many times word cat occurred in the string.

thank you so much for your help.
Kind Regards,

Viku

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    StringBuffer myBuffer = new StringBuffer("a is the first vowel in a e i o u");
    int charCount = 0;
    for(int i =0 ; i< myBuffer.length(); i++){
        if(myBuffer.charAt(i) == 'a' || myBuffer.charAt(i) == 'e' || 
                myBuffer.charAt(i) == 'i' || myBuffer.charAt(i) == 'o' ||
                myBuffer.charAt(i) == 'u'){
            charCount++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(nL + "Compute of Vowels in String: " + charCount);




}
```

}

Comment: It looks like you are counting vowels, not words.

Comment: First of all, forget about StringBuffer. A StringBuffer is useful when *constructing* a String. Not when analyzing it. String has all you need. And it should be replaced by StringBuilder anyway.

Comment: What do you think is not working in above code i.e. is that you want to count vowels or something else?

Comment: Where are you stuck? If we don't know which aspect of the problem you have trouble with we'll likely explain the wrong aspect ...

Comment: you can use regex if you need to find words

Comment: do you need to keep it as a `StringBuffer` (or as mentioned preferably `StringBuilder`) or can you `toString()` it?

Comment: The above program is working fine but i need a program which can count the occurrence of WORD and not alphabet. above program can count the occurrence of alphabet.

Comment: Sarthak -  Regex will work fine but the requirement is to use StringBuffer and StringTokenizer. any advise please.

Comment: Assaf - it has to be StringBuffer and StringTokenizer. Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is used to count the number of occurrence of vowels in a string and not the no. of occurrence of a particular word in a String. 
This is my solution.

#### Solution

```
String myBuffer = "a is the first vowel in a e i o u";

String checkWord = "a"; // this is the word to match in the string
int count = 0;
for(String word: myBuffer.split("\\s")) {
    if(word.equals(checkWord)) {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

I have split the string into an array of words using `myBuffer.split("\\s")` and compare each of the array elements using `String.equals()` method.

In the above code i am checking the occurrence of String "a" in "a is the first vowel in a e i o u".

#### Output

```
2
```

#### Solution using `StringBuffer` and `StringTokenizer`

```
StringBuffer myBuffer = new StringBuffer("a is the first vowel in a e i o u");
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(myBuffer.toString());
String checkWord = "a";
int count = 0;

while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String word = st.nextToken().toString();
    if(word.equals(checkWord)){
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Johny, Split method works with strings however i am require to use StringBuffer and split method is not working in there.

Comment: @Viku You should mark this as the accepted answer if this is the solution you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the sentence into an string array and iterate the array to find matching words

```
String s = String.valueOf(myBuffer);
String[] array = s.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i].equals("cat")){
        charCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem though, if the word alongside punctuation, then you'll pick that up too which may give you wrong results.